# How to set morethan max size charecters in NVARCHAR(MAX),sql Server2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am using

declare @insertsql nvarchar(MAX)

--above @insertsql for sp_executesql takes only nvarchar  as input

set @insertsql='--i am giving More than 10000 characters here -----'

EXEC sp_executesql @insertsql, N'@inXMLRequest XML OUTPUT', @inXMLRequest OUTPUT

how to insert morethan 10000 charecters in NVARCHAR(MAX) in sql server2005

can any one help please

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not have any problems here. What is @insertsql doing? Or are you building @insertsql from separate parts?

Comment: Elaborating on Ruben's comment, you might see a problem like this if you have something like REPLACE(@someNonMaxValue,'blah','blahblah') somewhere in the picture, because REPLACE on NVARCHAR(not MAX) returns NVARCHAR(not MAX). You would fix this by writing REPLACE(CAST(@someNonMaxValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'blah','blahblah')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to All,

i got the answer

Insted of using SP_Executesql directly we Executing nvarchar variable

Above we Are preparing @insertsql nvarchar variable morethan 8000 characters and it is giving to sp_executesql like this

EXEC sp_executesql @insertsql, N'@inXMLRequest XML OUTPUT',@inXMLRequest OUTPUT

insted of above query replaced with below query

Exec ('DeClare @inXMLRequest XML SET @inXMLRequest='------above 8000 characters---')

Finally we will execute that nvarchar string and get out put

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me when I use inline SQL statements instead of stored procs.

If you are hitting that ceiling, you may want to consider moving to stored procs.

Comment: Hi Raj,Thank you for helping ,i am also using inline sql,after that i am getting that out of range NVARCHAR string can u help for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter that you use for the command to run in sp_executesql (@insertsql in your case) is NVARCHAR(4000) not NVARCHAR(MAX) so you are limited to a 4000 character dynamic SQL command.

If you are running out of space in the variable, you'll need to do some code re-factoring.

Comment: hi,i used that @insertsql declared as Nvarchar(max) only.how to use more than 8000 characters fit into nvarchar(max).can u give any solution?

Comment: You can't.  The sp_executesql procedure only accepts 4000 characters based on it's input parameter definition.

Answer (score 0):

sp_executesql will accept an NVARCHAR(MAX) which can be longer than 4000, only it cannot be assigned all at once.  It needs to be assigned 4000 characters in a single assignment statement and then appended as shown here:

```
declare @strSQL nvarchar(max)
--@strSQL + REPLICATE(' ', 5000)+' ''ERROR!'''
--exec sp_executesql @strSQL 
SET @strSQL = N'SELECT'+ REPLICATE(' ', 3000)
SET @strSQL = @strSQL + REPLICATE(' ', 3000)+' ''This works'''
exec sp_executesql @strSQL
select LEN (@strSQL)
```